# Configuring AWS S3 Object expiration policy for Apache Spark Streaming checkpoint directory

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, apache-kafka, checkpointing

Does anyone have experience with expiration policies on the S3 buckets hosting spark streaming checkpoints directories? I have setup an application using spark streaming + kafka and I want to use an S3 bucket with a 24 hour expiration policy set to hold the checkpoint directory. However, I want to confirm that this won't interfere with the checkpoints functionality. So, has anyone does this before?

Comment: Spark Streaming manages it's own deletion of checkpoint data. Why do you need this?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov the bucket was configured prior to this use case. Just wanted to know if I could reuse it.